# How to get not null Adornerlayer for menuitem before expanding the menu

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, menu

Following code snippet gives me null adornerLayer

```
  Menu menu = (Menu)this.FindName("Menu");
  MenuItem menuItem = (MenuItem) menu.Items.GetItemAt(0);

  MenuItem subMenuItem = (MenuItem) menuItem.Items.GetItemAt(1);

  var layer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(subMenuItem);
  layer.Add(new SimpleCircleAdorner(subMenuItem));
```

In case that I'll add line:

```
menuItem.IsSubmenuOpen = true
```

Menu is expanded programatically and the adorner layer is not null.

Is there a possibility to get not-null adorner for not expanded menu? (for first time)

**Edit1:** Ok, it seems that visual tree is not created before menu-open. I'm still not sure how to trigger creation of visual tree programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a solution which returns not null adorner layer before the menu is expanded.

Therefore I introduced callback when visibility of particular menu item has been changed.

When menu is expanded the visibility is changed and I can get non-null Adorner.